# Как сделать, чтобы мой телеграм-бот на картинку ответил этой же картинкой?

Tags: python, файлы, telegram-bot, изображения

Я недавно начал заниматься ботами для Телеграма. Я решил сделать бота-обработчика фотографий, и для начала я пытался сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял картинку, похожую на ту, которую я ему отправлю. Я застрял как раз на моменте открытия файла: надо, чтобы это был файл, который я непосредственно отправляю боту. Думаю, что можно было открыть изображение по file_id, но не уверен до конца.
Есть ли способ такой же лёгкий, как с обычным эхо-ботом?

UPD: по всем предложенным советам написал вот это:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = 'photo')
def give_photo(photo):
    gp = photo.photo()
    gp.getFile(photo.from_user.id, 'file_id')
    bot.send_photo(photo.chat.id, gp)
```

Но при запуске кода возникает конфликт с мнимым getUpdates. Обратная связь у бота так работает?

---

Это фрагмент кода:

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = 'photo')
def give_photo(message):
    gp = message.photo()
    bot.copyMessage(message.chat.id, gp)
```

Там, скорее всего, что-то не совместилось.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом `getFile` и перешлите его обратно, ну или предоставьте пример вашей реализации, а мы поможем поправить

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#copymessage

Comment: Вот фрагмент кода: `import telebot
import config
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)@bot.message_handler(content_types = 'photo')
def give_photo(message):
    gp = message.photo()
    bot.copyMessage(message.chat.id, gp)
`